# Orden por distancia de elementos

Tags: javascript

Hace poco estuve un tiempo tratando de implementar el algoritmo llamado `Shortest Seek Time First` (SSTF) a base de simulación, sin embargo me estoy quedando sin tiempo y no logro descubrir como implementar bien el algoritmo, ya que lo tengo logrado a medias, el algoritmo parte de algo llamado `cilindros` donde un cilindro simula ser las regiones por donde se va a mover la aguja del disco duro, en pocas palabras, por donde va a pasar primero la aguja del disco duro.

El algoritmo `SSTF` funciona con base a la menor distancia que hay que recorrer de un cilindro a otro, es decir, **el orden es por menor distancia que hay que recorrer** para llegar de un cilindro a otro, yo tengo hecho lo siguiente:

```js
const timeList = new Array(4);

timeList[0] = {name: 'Open paint', time: 1000, cilinder: 83};
timeList[1] = {name: 'Open word', time: 2000, cilinder: 90};
timeList[2] = {name: 'Open photoshop', time: 4000, cilinder: 43};
timeList[3] = {name: 'Open gimpp', time: 3000, cilinder: 87};

function orderByLessCilinderDistance(processList){

    let procList = new Array(...processList);

    outer: for(let i = 0; i < procList.length - 1; i++){
        for(let j = i + 1; j < procList.length; j++){
            if(i > 0){
                if(Math.abs(procList[i].cilinder - procList[j].cilinder) > Math.abs(procList[i - 1].cilinder - procList[i].cilinder)){
                    const swap = procList[i];
                    procList[i] = procList[j];
                    procList[j] = swap;
                }
            }else{
                continue outer;
            }
        }
    }

    return procList

}

console.log(orderByLessCilinderDistance(timeList));
```

Donde casí lo tengo hecho, es decir lo que me retorna la función `orderByLessCilinderDistance` es:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Open paint",
    "time": 1000,
    "cilinder": 83
  },
  {
    "name": "Open gimpp",
    "time": 3000,
    "cilinder": 87
  },
  {
    "name": "Open photoshop",
    "time": 4000,
    "cilinder": 43
  },
  {
    "name": "Open word",
    "time": 2000,
    "cilinder": 90
  }
]
```

Lo cuál si es correcto, excepto los ultimos dos, debido a que el orden deberia ser así:

```
cilinder: 83,
cilinder: 87,
cilinder: 90,
cilinder: 43
```

Debido a que según este orden de 83 a 87 hay solo 4, de 87 a 90 hay solo 3, de 90 a 43 esta la distancia mas larga, (los primeros dos son correctos debido a que si en vez de poner 87 de primero, pusiera 90, entonces la distancia ya no sería 4 en el primero, sería 7, lo cuál es erroneo para el algoritmo).

Que cambios o arreglos puedo hacer a mi código para obtener el resultado que deseo?, ya intente un sort personalizado, pero igual me lo ordenaba de menor a mayor o de mayor a menor, pero no este orden que quiero.

Tener en cuenta que el primer elemento siempre será el primero, osea el primero es el punto de partida y siempre va a estar en el mismo sitio, los otros deberán ordenarse de acuerdo a la distancia minima o recorrido mas corto entre estos y el primero ya sea que el numero sea mayor al cilindro o sea menor, lo que cuenta es ordenar de acuerdo a las distancias que hay entre un cilindro y el otro partiendo del primer elemento y que el primero siempre sea el primero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razon por la que falla es porque **realmente nunca estas calculando la distancia que hay del punto de inicio con respecto a todos los demas**

Si prestas atención, siempre estas intercambiando si la distancia de `i-j > i-(i-1)`.

#### Solución:

Lo que deberías hacer es **primero calcular la distancia a todos y luego intercambiar con el que este más cerca**.

```js
let timeList = [{
  name: 'Open paint',
  time: 1000,
  cilinder: 83
}, {
  name: 'Open word',
  time: 2000,
  cilinder: 90
}, {
  name: 'Open photoshop',
  time: 4000,
  cilinder: 43
}, {
  name: 'Open gimpp',
  time: 3000,
  cilinder: 87
}];

function orderByLessCilinderDistance(processList) {

  let list = [...processList];
  let i = 1; // salteamos el 0
  for (i; i < list.length; i++) {

    // Buscamos el que este a menor distancia del anterior
    let idx = 0;
    let minDistance = Infinity;
    for (let j = i; j < list.length; j++) {

      let distance = Math.abs(list[i - 1].cilinder - list[j].cilinder);
      if (distance < minDistance) {
        minDistance = distance;
        idx = j;
      }
    }

    // Intercambiamos
    if (idx != i) {
      let node = list[idx];
      list[idx] = list[i];
      list[i] = node;
    }
  }
  return list;

}

console.log(orderByLessCilinderDistance(timeList));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos funciona a la perfección!, se me fueron las pinzas al olvidarme que podia declarar los objetos dentro del array así como lo hiciste en tu respuesta, funciona perfectamente!